# How to logout all users from Server?

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services

I want to update some database table for that I need to logout all the active users so that I can restart EC2 and RDS server. I tried to delete all session files but I think it's not the right way to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you think so? Or, in other words, why do you think there should be a better way that won't involve erasing all the session files?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **database-sessions** in your project, all the login sessions are stored in the database itself... Then clearing the session table in db will logout all the active sessions..

Ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions

Answer (score 0):

You can force php to destroy all sessions

```
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
```

I suggest that it will be better if you're using the Database sessions.